# Android Access Token Encryption

Tags: android, encryption

I'm looking to encrypt my access token that is generated when the user inputs a username and password. The question I'm asking here is what are the different ways of doing this and what would the community think is the best method to do so. I've looked at Cryptography and Keystore but not sure if these are the right way to go? I'm a noob to encryption so any documentation would also be very helpful.

Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with android SecretKeySpec class

for encryption

```
public void setPassCode(String   value) throws Exception { 

    try {

        SecretKeySpec sks = null; 
        sks = getEncryptKey();

        byte[] userLatENC=null;

        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,sks ); 
        userLatENC = c.doFinal(value.getBytes());

        passCode = Base64.encodeToString(userLatENC, Base64.DEFAULT);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

for decryption

```
public String getPassCode() throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec sks = null; 

        try {

            String encVal = "pass_code";

            if (encVal.isEmpty()) {
                return encVal;
            }


            sks = getDecryptKey();

            byte[] latDEC=null;


            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);

            latDEC = c.doFinal(Base64.decode(encVal, Base64.DEFAULT));




            return new String(latDEC);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Get Encrypted Key

```
private SecretKeySpec getEncryptKey() throws Exception{

        SecretKeySpec sks = null; 
        SecretKey key =null;
        byte[]  keyToSave;


        try {
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());



            SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            sr.setSeed("any data used as random seed".getBytes());
            KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");


            kg.init(128, sr);
            key= kg.generateKey();
            keyToSave =key.getEncoded();
            sks = new SecretKeySpec(keyToSave, "AES");

            ks.load(null,null);
            ks.setKeyEntry("aliasKey",key,null, null);


            FileOutputStream ksout = context.openFileOutput("keystore_android", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ks.store(ksout, null);
            ksout.close();

            return sks;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

For Decrypted Key

```
private SecretKeySpec getDecryptKey() throws Exception{

        SecretKeySpec sks = null;

        try {

            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            FileInputStream fis = null;

            fis = context.openFileInput("keystore_android");



            keyStore.load(fis,null);
            sks=new SecretKeySpec((keyStore.getKey("aliasKey", null)).getEncoded(), "AES");

            return sks;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a go. How safe is this?

Comment: According to my knowledge this will work without any issue :)

Comment: Quick question, where is passCode being generated from? Is that meant to be my access token?

Comment: yes.may access token..what ever String you want to encrypt and decrypt.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I decrypt `javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete` and I can't figure out what's wrong :( any ideas?